# How to use the same data set for multiple series in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I'm fairly new to Highcharts. We were previously using Logi Analytics, which did 
a lot of stuff in the background that we had no control over. Now that were trying to re-create the same charts, were running into issues on how to do some of these things. I am trying to use the same data set for multiple series elements. For example, I will have a column chart, then a line chart on top of it. If it helps, I keep this code in a .ts file and compile into JS to deploy. Here's what I currently have that works:

```
let myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                //do something
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'My Title'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: dataCategories
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Percentages'
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Data Table',
            data: data,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    ]
});
```

My data is embedded with Java. Example of data:

```
 let data = 
                [
                    {
                        'location': 'someplace',
                        'dept': '999',
                        'deptDescription': '999 DEPT',
                        'code': '',
                        'name': 'NO NAME',
                        'hours1': 32.5,
                        'hours2': 4.7,
                        'hours3': 0.0,
                        'hours4': 0.0
                    }
         ];
```

How I set my yAxis and categories:

```
for (let row of data) {
    row.y = row.hours1;
    dataCategories.push(row.deptDescription);
}
```

I want to use the same data because I have the same x axis and my data contains the new y axis as well. Possibly something like this:

```
    series: [
        {
            type: 'column'
            name: 'Data Table',
            data: data,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Data Table2',
            data: data,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/s2moLn3b/. Also I can see that your data has the wrong structure. Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.

Comment: Thanks, and that would work if my yAxis was the same, but it's not. Also, as long as the data has a 'y' property, it will accept it. I am probably going to have to manually create the extra array of 'y' values.